# UILabel disappear after align right

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am adding an `UIlabel` to the background of my`TableView`. It works fine if I don't set the alignment of the label. After I set the text align right using `[nameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];` the text (the label) disappears.

Here is my code:

```
 UIView *backGroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 640, 910)];
    [backGroundView addSubview:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:
                                     [UIImage imageNamed:@"homeimg1.jpg"]]];

    UILabel *nameLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 320, 44)];
    [nameLabel setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentRight];
    nameLabel.text = @"test";

    [backGroundView addSubview:nameLabel];
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backGroundView;
```

when comment out alignment:
[2 http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5994/9BhKVX.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5994/9BhKVX.png)

when set alignment:
[1 http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5683/W5crrQ.png](http://imageshack.com/a/img537/5683/W5crrQ.png)

thanks in advance!

Comment: your rect is too wide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You label has width equal to device's screen width, and label has origin x 50 px. So, when you are setting text alignment to the right, your text on the label is just out of screen's visible area. Just set this frame to your label `CGRectMake(50., 0., 270., 44.)` and everything will be alright. Good Luck!